# Porting Android

Tags: android, porting

i want to have some knowledge on porting android on linux devices. I am a web and android developer but now i want to port android on some hardware which you could suggest is easy for the beginners to start with. 
I don't feel like buying a mobile phone this time i want to make a mobile phone :)
Please help me achieve this goal.

regards
Abhishek Talwar

Comment: I'm not sure whether I really understood your question, but Android SDK comes with emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you're asking is pretty complex.

Do you want to BUILD your own cellphone from scratch?

This would take a lot of knowledge and development time. You could get some GSM development boards to experiment with that. Something like these:

http://www.sparkfun.com/search/results?term=gsm&what=products

You could get an Arduino and use one of the arduino linux ports. The arduino could handle the gsm module and an lcd screen.

This is extremely complicated though.

If its android porting you're interested in, I suggest just getting a mobile phone and then porting android to it.  It WILL be complicated and you better get something you can easily develop for. Windows Mobile phones would be my suggestion as there are a lot of active programs to port android to those.